# Pygame - Rotating image won't stop stretching

Tags: python, pygame

Hi all when I run the following code the image "Car1.jpg" enlarges at a rapid rate going off the screen and then crashing with the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Indy 500\Indev V0\Indy 500.py", line 72, in 
>       Car1.update(deltaTime)
>     File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Indy 500\Indev V0\Indy 500.py", line 45, in update
>       self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.direction)
>   pygame.error: Width or height is too large

```
#Necessary imports to make the game run.
import math
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import sys
import time

#This sets up the Display, Framerate and Caption.
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Indy 500 Remastered")

class Car (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Initalises the 10 cars in game with their default stats.
    def __init__ (self, image, position, MaxSpeed, Acceleration, Handling):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = os.path.join("Graphics", image)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.image)
        self.position = position
        self.speed = self.direction = 0
        self.MaxSpeed = MaxSpeed
        self.acceleration = Acceleration
        self.handling = Handling
        self.k_left = self.k_right = self.k_down = self.k_up = 0

    def update(self, deltaTime):
        self.direction = 0
        self.speed += (self.k_up + self.k_down)
        if self.speed > self.MaxSpeed:
            self.speed = self.MaxSpeed
        if self.speed < -self.MaxSpeed:
            self.speed = self.MaxSpeed
        self.direction += (self.k_right + self.k_left)
        print(self.direction)
        dx, dy = self.position
        radian = self.direction * (math.pi /180)
        dx += -self.speed * (math.sin(radian))
        dy += -self.speed * (math.cos(radian))
        print (dx)
        print (dy)
        self.position = ((dx, dy))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.direction)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        self.rect.center = self.position

rect = screen.get_rect()
Car1 = Car("Car1.jpg", rect.center, 2, 10, 10)

#This manages animations to make sure that the screen will refresh.
while True:
    #This section will get the framerate and print it into the shell.
    pygame.event.get()
    deltaTime = clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if not hasattr(event, "key"): continue
        down = event.type == KEYDOWN
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            Car1.k_right = down * -3
        elif event.key == K_LEFT:
            Car1.k_left = down * 3
        elif event.key == K_UP:
            Car1.k_up = down * 2
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            Car1.k_up = down * -2
        elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit(0)
    screen.fill ((0,0,170))
    Car1.update(deltaTime)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Is there any possible way of fixing this? When I am printing dx,dy and self.direction, then only self.direction changes to 3 or -3. Is each rotation enlarging the image too much? What can be done to fix this?

Thanks, 
Adam.

Answer (score 3):

You should not keep making rotations of rotations of rotations. It's a bit like photocopying a photocopy. You should keep one master copy of the image, untransformed, then create all the different rotations from the same master.

Whenever you call rotate on an image, what you get back is a larger image. This is necessary because all images are rectangular - if you rotate a square image 45 degrees, the only way to avoid chopping off any corners is to make the resulting image 40% wider and taller than the original. You will also find that the rotated copy loses some quality, because the square pixels can't line up perfectly unless the rotation is a multiple of 90 degrees. So if you keep rotating the result of the last rotation, you will get a bigger and bigger (with more and more empty padding around the edges) and an increasingly distorted image until eventually it's too big to handle and your program crashes or your computer slows to a crawl.

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
def __init__(self, image_filename, ...):
    ...
    self.original_image = pygame.image.load(image_filename)
    ...

def render(self, screen):
    ...
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
    screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y)))
    ...

def turn(self, clockwise_angle):
    '''
    Rotate clockwise by the given angle in degrees.
    (Or indeed counter-clockwise if the angle is negative.)
    '''
    # Note: self.angle is positive for counter-clockwise
    # rotation, to match pygame.transform.rotate.
    self.angle -= clockwise_angle
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What would you suggest to do then for simulating a car turning a corner? Would it be something along the lines of this: image = "car1.jpg" rotation = 0. say first pass makes it rotate 10 degrees and then second 20. it would rotate the original 10, go back to 0 and then to 20?

Comment: I've edited in a suggestion of a general approach you could take.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give this a go tomorrow! Very new to Pygame and OOP. Only used to making Procedural Programs and Text Based Adventures.